# Python Imaging Library and JPEGs on MacOsX

Tags: python, macos, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I've gotten a hold of [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and installed the PNG support stuff just fine. I am however having issues with the[JPEG Library](http://www.ijg.org/).

The default setting for it is nothing but they suggest "/home/libraries/jpeg-6b". On the Mac that directory doesn't exist, the library is however installed fine, here's the output of the install.

```
/usr/bin/install -c cjpeg /usr/local/bin/cjpeg
/usr/bin/install -c djpeg /usr/local/bin/djpeg
/usr/bin/install -c jpegtran /usr/local/bin/jpegtran
/usr/bin/install -c rdjpgcom /usr/local/bin/rdjpgcom
/usr/bin/install -c wrjpgcom /usr/local/bin/wrjpgcom
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./cjpeg.1 /usr/local/man/man1/cjpeg.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./djpeg.1 /usr/local/man/man1/djpeg.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./jpegtran.1 /usr/local/man/man1/jpegtran.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./rdjpgcom.1 /usr/local/man/man1/rdjpgcom.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./wrjpgcom.1 /usr/local/man/man1/wrjpgcom.1
```

I tried pointing PIL to /usr/local/bin/cjpeg, cjpeg and so on but it never recognised it. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, the only way to have working Python + PIL on OS X was to install both from [ports](http://www.macports.org/). I've never managed to get fully functional PIL under either system Python or installed manually from python.org. Maybe you could try this approach?

Comment: Upon installing jpeg with port it started to work. Thank you :)